# Regex in R to extract words before a special character

Tags: r, regex

I having a dataframe of part of speech tagged strings 
Example:

```
best_JJS phone_NN only_RB issue_NN camera_NN sensor_NN have_VB mind_NN own_JJ
```

I want to remove the tags after/and the '_' so that I have the output

```
best phone only issue camera sensor have mind own
```

I am using R and I couldn't find an appropriate regex for the gsub function.
I tried this.

```
sentence= c("best_JJS phone_NN only_RB issue_NN camera_NN sensor_NN have_VB mind_NN own_JJ")
o1=gsub("\\_.*","",sentence, perl = T)
```

But This removes entire string after the first underscore. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `_[A-Z]+` TRE pattern with `gsub`:

```
sentence <- c("best_JJS phone_NN only_RB issue_NN camera_NN sensor_NN have_VB mind_NN own_JJ")
gsub("_[A-Z]+","",sentence)
[1] "best phone only issue camera sensor have mind own"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/bDozcG)

The `_[A-Z]+` pattern matches an underscore (`_`, note it does not have to be escaped in a regex pattern) and one or more (`+`) uppercase ASCII letters (`[A-Z]`).

You may further precise the pattern, say, to only match the `_` if it is preceded with a word char and match uppercase letters only when followed with a word boundary:

```
"\\B_[A-Z]+\\b
```

In case you want to create a very specific regex for the POS values, you may use alternation:

```
"\\B_(JJ|NN|CC|[VR]B)\\b"
```

And continue adding `|<code>` to the regex pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much!! That was of great help.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew: Sorry. I am still figuring out how to use this forum effectively.Thanks again.